# Count Number of 1's in A Binary Representation of N, RECURSIVELY. in JAVA

Tags: java, recursion

I understand the concept that the number of 1's in N is the same as N/2 if it's even, and N/2 + 1 if the number is odd, but I don't understand how to do it recursively.

Also, say I input 10101 into my machine, and I do N/2, it does 505 instead of the binary division. Do I have to convert back and forth each time?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-homework way to answer this: [`Integer.bitCount`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int))

:-P

Answer (score 1):

Read the question carefully: The number of 1's in N is the same as the number of 1's in N/2 if N is even, and the same as the (number of 1's in N/2) + 1 if N is odd.

How can you tell if N is even or odd, just by looking at the bit string? (Hint: think about what each column represents: 64's, 32's, 16's, ...)

Think about what N/2 means in terms of the bit operations: compute a few on paper, like 8/2, 7/2, 5/2 and look for a pattern.

Comment: @Jim: No problem. Consider upvoting some of the answers, and possibly accepting one of them.

Answer (score 1):

When you use recursion, it's important to identify the "base" case: the condition where no further recursion takes place. I think if you are counting bits, the base case would be where the value is zero, i.e., there are no bits set that remain to be counted.

You're correct that the number of 1s is the same in N and N/2 if N is even, and the same as N/2 + 1 if N is odd. The interesting "bit" is the "+ 1". If N is odd, where would that bit be? Think about the bit patterns for 1, 3, 9, 17, 19… any odd number you care to check. Do you notice a pattern?